# Angular ServiceWorker fails with TrustedTypes

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker, trusted-types

For a single SPA Angular application, I want to use service workers ; but it conflicts with my CSP security rules...

> main.ts:5 This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment.

> Service worker registration failed with: TypeError: Failed to execute
> 'register' on 'ServiceWorkerContainer': This document requires
> 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment.

I tried to fix it with DOMPurify, then withcustom trusted-types policy, but without success...

**Dependencies :**

- trusted-types 2.0.0
- angular 16.2.6

**app.config.ts**

```js
// [...]
import {trustedTypes} from 'trusted-types';

const myPolicy = trustedTypes.createPolicy('custom', {
  createScriptURL(dirty) {
    return dirty;
  },
})
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    // [...]
    provideServiceWorker(myPolicy.createScriptURL(`/ngsw-worker.js`) as unknown as string, {
      enabled: !isDevMode(),
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**CSP headers**

> require-trusted-types-for 'script'; trusted-types custom dompurify
> angular angular#bundler;

I don't know what I'm missing here :/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45145 explains

> Since navigator.serviceWorker.register() is considered an injection
> sink and you are using Trusted Types in your app, you must ensure that
> the string used to specify the SW script is trusted. How to do this
> depends on how you implement your policies.

and points to [Angular.io as an example of a PWA that has solved this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/aio/src/app/app.module.ts).

As advised, I installed the https://www.npmjs.com/package/safevalues package and made the relevant changes:

app.module.ts:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register(
      unwrapResourceUrl(trustedResourceUrl`ngsw-worker.js`) as string,
      {
        enabled: environment.production,
        // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
        // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
        registrationStrategy: "registerWhenStable:30000",
      }
    ),
```

After that, you just need to add "google#safe" to the trusted-types region of your CSP, e.g.

> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-inline'; trusted-types angular angular#bundler google#safe;
> require-trusted-types-for 'script'; font-src fonts.gstatic.com;
> frame-ancestors 'none';